# Returning Transformed Object Based On Some Other Objects Property

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

Is there a way to return an object from a JavaScript function based on some properties value?

For example:

```
let personDetails = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 25,
    occupation: 'Software Engineer',
    hobby: 'Not Programming on a Thursday night',
    pets: ['Dog', 'Cat']
};
```

Imagine some `Person` model:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number:
}
```

Also, a `PersonDetails` model:

```
export interface PersonDetails {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    occupation: string,
    hobby: 'string',
    pets: string[]
}
```

And then finally, doing something like the following:

```
public persons: Person[];
public personDetails: PersonDetails[];

let person = this.personDetails.map(this.toPersonModel.bind(this));

toPersonModel(personDetails: PersonDetails[]): Person {
    // If a person has more than 2 pets, return a simplified model
    // Can we do something like a filter here?
    if (personDetails.pets.length > 2) {
        return {
            name: personDetails.name,
            age: personDetails.age
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that there only be 2 keys in the returned object?

Comment: Yes. In this case, it needs to be the same structure as the return type, in this case, a `Person`

Comment: Since `Person` is a subset of `PersonDetails`, why not just cast as the former?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
export interface PersonDetails {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    occupation: string,
    hobby: string,
    pets: string[]
}
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
var reducer = function(persons:Person[], personDetails:PersonDetails):Person[] {
    if (personDetails.pets.length > 0) {
        let person: Person = {
            name: personDetails.name,
            age: personDetails.age,
        }
        persons.push(person);
    }
    return persons;
}
let personDetails: PersonDetails[] = [
    {
        name: 'Alice',
        age: 29,
        occupation: 'Analyst',
        hobby: 'Ham radio',
        pets: ['Cat']
    },
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        age: 25,
        occupation: 'Software Engineer',
        hobby: 'Not Programming on a Thursday night',
        pets: ['Dog', 'Cat']
    },
];
var persons = personDetails.reduce(reducer,[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that you have inheritance. So you can build actual base types.

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export interface PersonDetails extends Person {
    occupation: string;
    hobby: 'string';
    pets: string[];
}
```

but because these are interfaces they only say that this object must at least have these properties, and sense our Details object IS a Person its useless(casting won't remove the extra properties) to try and return it casted as a Person.

I would suggest using classes instead.

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(args: Partial<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, args);
  }
}

export class Details extends Person {
  pets: any[];

  constructor(args: Partial<Details>) {
    super(args);
  }
}

export function PetCheck(p: Details): Person {
  if (p.pets.length > 2) {
    return new Person(p);
  }

  return new Details(p);
}
```